# How to implement an ABAC policy using RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, xacml, abac, alfa

I want to implement the attribute-based access control (ABAC) policy using RoR(Ruby on Rails). I found an authorization library named (IronHide). I want to know how to create rules and use this library according to my application.

Comment: Check out AuthZForce (open source) or Axiomatics (where I work). These are the most complete ABAC libraries.

Comment: Look into ALFA, the abbreviated language for authorization - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)

Comment: please can you give me the link or the documentation of Axiomatics where i can find the steps to use it with RoR.